# In ng grid, how to click on a row and click a button in the row without conflict?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

OK, here is the case: I have a grid , the last column is a button to delete this row, and I also need to click on a row to jump to a new page. But when I click the delete button, it will also jump to the new page, how can I resolve the confict? Thanks!

In controller:

```
$scope.gridOptions =
        {
            data: 'students',
            columnDefs: [
                {field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'},
                {field: 'school', displayName: 'Name'},
                {field: '', displayName: 'Delete', cellTemplate:
                '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()">' +
                '<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="deleteStudent(row)"></a></div>'}
            ]
        };

$scope.deleteStudent = function(row) {....}

$scope.selectStuent = function(row) {$location.path(....)}
```

In html:

```
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions" ng-click="selectStudent()"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working with ui-grid which is the latest version of ng-grid. Here is how I resolve the similar issue. It seems to work well with ng-grid.

```
<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();deleteStudent(row)"></a>
```

I made a simple example in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/awwitB?p=preview) to demonstrate it.